# uilabel border gets distorted after rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I am trying to rotate `UILabel` but after rotation its border gets distorted and appears zig-zag. I must have a border in my label so it is not looking good. I am using following code to rotate it:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; // arguments are optional
lblText.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

How can I make the border smooth?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lblText.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 3 pixel transparent border to the inner view and rasterize it so that the pixels interpolate smoothing the border.

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 3; 
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor; 
view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Now the final trick is to add some shadow. This will make the border look somehow more solid.

```
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1); 
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1; 
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor
```

Don't forget to add `QuartzCore` Framework.

Comment: Hi Sapan, thanks for replying, I tried it but it didnt work I am still having wavy borders in uilabel.

Comment: Strong image disorder after enabling rasterisation.